# Mobile app development: "No qmlviewer installed" when trying to access Qt 5 in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

As we all know, trying to force Qt Creator to use qmlscene instead of qmlviewer is like trying to force Eclipse, after already having installed JDT, to use CDT instead. Googling "No qmlviewer installed", of course, does return [this Qt forum result](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19787), but there's no way in the world the "-qpa" flag is the default Qt Creator behavior.

By the way, yes I HAVE registered qmlscene with Qt Creator (as an external tool), and yes, I HAVE tried to get Qt 5 working with the Creator (to no avail). As for the PATH variable: It's defined **system-wide**, in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile (respectively) and "echo $PATH" does reveal /opt/qt5/bin in there. And even qmlscene causes problems, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235763/why-ubuntu-components-0-1-missing-from-qtcreator), **only on an Ubuntu 12.10 machine**. So there's no reason for Qt Creator to be acting up.

Thanks for the help in advance...