# Unable to build QtQuick 2 projects

Tags: qml, qt-creator, qt5

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04, and I have the following packages installed:

- `qt5-default` (5.2.1)
- `qtcreator` (3.0.1-0ubuntu4)
- `qml` (5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1)

They were installed from the official repos and are the latest stable versions at the time of writing this.

I have a small project which only consists of three QML files. Clicking the **Run** button in Qt Creator runs `qmlscene` fine, like it should.

However, the **Build** button is disabled. In **Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions**, the installed Qt version (5.2.1) is detected, but it has [a warning sign and a message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYosD.png):

> No qmlviewer installed.

As I understand, the package `qml` is supposed to act as the QML Viewer for Qt5, and it is installed. I tried purging, reinstalling, etc., but to no avail. Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Thank you.

PS: I did look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245814/mobile-app-development-no-qmlviewer-installed-when-trying-to-access-qt-5-in-q), but their installation and environment are apparently different.

**EDIT:** According to [this post](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19787), it seemed to be an issue as of Qt Creator 2.6, however, I'm using 3.0 and couldn't find any resources for it.

Comment: Did you follow this guide http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/ ?

Comment: @TuKsn, no. Since I aim to develop a pure QML2 app, and not a Unity app, I did not follow it. I assume it is not required to install the Ubuntu SDK for pure Qt apps, right?

Comment: Yes I think so, perhaps this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469306/no-qmlviewer-installed

Comment: @TuKsn, thanks, some info from there might be useful. I made an edit.